# Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance() calling Multiple times (Increments on each request)

Tags: c#, ajax

I need to call a function after all content on the page is refreshed and it should call only once each time its called. So I wrote the below code.

For some reason, I get an 'Uncaught TypeError: a[b] is not a function' after it logged message1+message2 twice in the console.

If I move the remove_pageLoaded code to under console.log(message1, message2), it causes an infinite logging in the console.

If I completely remove 'remove_pageLoaded', every time the instance 'PageRequestManager' gets added up and increments on each request.

I found a very similar question, but those are the answers I just mentioned and tried. 
I even created a variable and assigned Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance() to that. It doesn't work either.

```
function sendMessage(msg1, msg2) 
{
        try
        {

            Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(fnSendMessage(msg1, msg2));
            Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().remove_pageLoaded(fnSendMessage(msg1, msg2));
        }
        catch (e)
        {
            console.log(e.message+" - Error in sendMessage");
        }

    };

    function fnSendMessage(message1, message2)
    {
        console.log(message1 + message2);           
    };
```

Comment: You're supposed to pass a *reference* to a function to `add_pageLoaded` and `remove_pageLoaded`. Right now you're *invoking* the function and only pass its return value (which is `undefined`, since it doesn't return anything). Try `add_pageLoaded(fnSendMessage)` instead.

Comment: Didn't get, could you please make it clear!